# How to add tags "with friends" when posting to fb wall using

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How we can add special tag "with friends" using facebook graph api, like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwlq0fa6o4p09h5/Facebook%202014-07-22%2015-26-59%202014-07-22%2015-27-12.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `taggable_friends` API to get IDs of Friends you can tag and then make an API call to `/me/feed` to post an update with tagged friends.

You can get taggable IDs by doing:

```
$taggable = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/taggable_friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Then using an ID from that response to post to wall:

```
$story = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
              'message' => 'test', 'tags' => $tags, 'place' => '195383960551614'
            ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

[This tutorial shows the complete code.](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/) Note that you need to use a Place in order to tag friends. Using a Page with no address hides the location.